# C# Using Multiple Database Results with Listboxes that (when item is selected) Display Info in Textboxes

Tags: c#, .net, database, logic

I am working on a Cook Book using a database. I have been working with tutorials to build my project since I'm still just a novice.

I have asked before how to search a database using a button, and the help was so quick, I'll have to ask another question.

Here's the problem:

My form allows a user to find recipes that have a certain ingredient. It allows them to type an ingredient in the textbox, and the button shows all the results (the recipes' names) in a listbox. That part has been successfully coded, thanks to the help here. Once the list box is populated, though, I'd like the user to be able to select a recipe from the list box, and the textboxes next to the listbox fill with the particular recipe's data information (such as ingredients, directions, and additional comments).

What recipes populate the listbox are up to the user, so I can't really code this without some serious logic, right?

Here is the code for my entire form:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Collections;


namespace Cookbook
{
    public partial class BrowseIngredients : Form
    {
        public BrowseIngredients()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        SqlConnection con;
        SqlDataAdapter dataAdapt;
        DataSet dataRecipe;
        int MaxRows = 0;
        int inc = 0;


        private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("Exit Cook Book?", "Exit?", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel) == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                Application.Exit();
            }
        }

        private void btnBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BrowseRecipes goBack = new BrowseRecipes();

            Close();
            goBack.Show();
        }

        private void howToSearchToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("To look for recipes with ingredients you have, simply type in the first ingredient you have to cook. \r\n To narrow your search, add another ingredient you'd like to search for in the recipe results.", "Search by Ingredients");
        }


        private void BrowseIngredients_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            con = new SqlConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Documents and Settings\\Cady Wong\\My Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\Cookbook\\Cookbook\\Recipes.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
            dataRecipe = new DataSet();

            con.Open();

           string sql = "SELECT* From CookBookRecipes";
           dataAdapt = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
           dataAdapt.Fill(dataRecipe, "CookBookRecipes");
           NavigateRecords();
           MaxRows = dataRecipe.Tables["CookBookRecipes"].Rows.Count;

            con.Close();

        }

        private void NavigateRecords()
        {
            DataRow dRow = dataRecipe.Tables["CookBookRecipes"].Rows[inc];

        }


//This is the search and populate listbox code //


        private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            if (tbSearch.TextLength >= 1)
           {
                //MessageBox.Show("This will work when you put in a word!");

               listBox1.Items.Clear();

                string searchOut = tbSearch.Text;
                int result = 0;

                DataRow[] returnRows;

                returnRows = dataRecipe.Tables["CookBookRecipes"].Select("Recipe_Ingredients LIKE '*" + searchOut + "*'");


                result = returnRows.Length;

//This allows mutiple results to be seen one line after another //

                if (result > 0)
                {
                    string temp ="";
                    DataRow rowBack;
                    for (int index = 0; index < returnRows.Count(); index++ )
                    {
                        rowBack = returnRows[index];
                        listBox1.Items.Add(rowBack[0].ToString());
                        temp += rowBack[0].ToString();
                        temp += "\n";
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("No record");
                }

           }

           else
            {
               MessageBox.Show("Please enter an ingredient to search for!", "Search");
           }
        }

    }
}
```

If you need more information, just let me know!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: So when the user clicks a listbox item do you need to make another database call? like `select * from table where recipe='quiche'` or something of that nature?

Comment: @Nick: I suppose, since all that data is in the database. The listbox will be populated by the user, so I need some computer logic to figure out which recipe is being selected, in any sort or order, and how to take that recipe and offer up the rest of its details. Does that make any sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I haven't really provided the answer- more bane you with a few tips that hopefully will push you forward, not just on this project, but as a programmer in general.

*On a slight side note before I continue, the tags "multiple" and "logic" are a perculiar choice for your question*

Regarding BrowseIngredients_Load:

Here you use a SqlConnection which implements the [IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) interface.  The best practice (and it's very highly recommended) is to always use the [Using Block Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) when working with objects that implement IDispoable (at least where possible).

```
using (con = New SqlConnection(connectionString)){
    ' use the connection within these bracers
}
' because you used this pattern, the object is disposed correctly, memory deallocated, etc
```

The next bit of advice would be to take a look at Linq to SQL (L2S for short).  L2S is an [Object-Relational Mapper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping).  Sounds complicated but basically means it is responsible for mapping your database objects (Tables, Views, etc) to your Domain Model (Classes, Strucutres, etc).  Probably again sounds a bit complicated, but trust me, check out these dead simple tutorials and you'll love it:

[CodeProject Article including Source Code](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/LINQSQLCS.aspx)

[Part 1 of Scott Gu's Blog/Tutorials](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx)

[Good ol' MSDN Introduction to L2S](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386927.aspx)

*NB: There are many ORMs available, Microsoft itself also provides Entity Framework, but L2S should be easy to learn and arm you with enough knowledge to make educated choices towards ORM alternatives in the future*

If you go with L2S (which once you've spent a couple hours with, you'll find you'll use over writing out T-SQL in your code **every** time) it solves a couple other issues, such as introducing [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) which Linq would handle for you.

It would also solve your overall problem, or almost.  With Linq to SQL, displaying the Recipes data would be simple because they would just be the properties of a class.

```
txtIngredients.Text = myAutoGeneratedLinqRecipe.Ingredients;
```

I hope that helps get you on your way, I'm sure somebody else will give you the code to complete your exercise without introducing new code patterns and technologies ^^

EDIT: A quick exmaple of the using block so you get the idea:

```
Private void BrowseIngredients_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connStr = "Data Source=.....etc";
    using (con = New SqlConnection(connStr))
    {
        con.Open
        ' get your data here - if you were losing Linq, you wouldnt have to worry
        ' about connections or Sql at all ;-)
        con.Close
    } ' this ensures that the connection is disposed correctly, even if for example
      ' you throw an exception inside the block which isn't caught
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I will look at those tutorials. By the way, I couldn't think of any tags that existed for my question, so that's why some of them are kind of weird.

Comment: No problem @C Wong, I think you would have been fine just using the first 3 (C#, .net, database - that describes the problem closely enough).  If you can get through any one of those tutorials and not know the answer to your own question, I'll eat my hat =D

Comment: About the using '(con = New SqlConnection(connectionString)){ connection code }' does that go directly under the 'using system.Collections' in my code?

Comment: Okay, thank you. I'm trying to wrap my head around this. With Linq to Sql, I could rewrite my whole code without connection strings or dataAdapters or commandBuilders or all that other stuff?

Comment: Absolutely.  You have something called a DataModel which is almost literally a picture (of your database).  L2S creates all the classes you need for you.  If you check out those tutorials you'll see how to use your "DataContext" (which you'll need a conenction string for but in simple environments linq can save this for you under the hood so you don't have to have it in code) which in turn will fetch the objects you need to populate your listview, or the textboxes, etc.  Check it out and let us know if you have any problems.  Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much for the help and the patience! I may have many questions to ask you in the future, so you might be hearing a lot from me. It's a case of "no good deed goes unpunished." :)